# Jquery More divs width!

Tags: jquery

I have an div wrapper and some div-s inside of it.
Can I calculate all div-s width inside the wrapper and give the total width to the wrapper? 
Thank you!

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="image"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>
 <div class="image"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>
 <div class="image"><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>
 <div class="image"><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>
 <div class="image"><img src="images/5.jpg"></div>
 <div class="image"><img src="images/6.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function calcWidth() {
    var width = 0;
    $("#wrapper").find("div").each(function(){
        width += $(this).width();
    });
    return width;
}

$("#wrapper").width(calcWidth());
```

Like this?

Comment: Why not `$('#wrapper div').each(...)`;?

Comment: Because the code block wasn't in the start post so I didn't knew if the div's he needed where direct childs of the wrapper. Your example is better as long the div's are direct childs of the wrapper.